# Invalid OData path and Invalid action error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to create a ODataController and have it like so:

```
public class ProductSetController : ODataController
{
    public IQueryable<ProductRef> GetAllProducts(string StoreId, string flag)
    {
            long lStoreId = Convert.ToInt64(StoreId);

            var featuredProducts = (from b in new SomeContext().SomeInfluence
                                    where b.SomeInfluenceTypeId == 1234 && b.StoreId == lStoreId && b.IsDeleted == false
                                    select b.ProductId).ToList();

            return (from b in new OProdctSubscriptionContext(lStoreId).ProductRef where featuredProducts.Contains(b.ProductId) select b).AsQueryable();


    }
}
```

And this in WebApiConfig's Register method:

```
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<ProductRef>("ProductSet");
        config.Routes.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
```

To test it I made a call like so:

```
http://localhost:32944/odata/ProductSet/GetAllProducts?StoreId=5010&flag="N"
```

The browser printed out this error:

> {"$id":"1","Message":"The OData path is
>   invalid.","ExceptionMessage":"Invalid action detected.
>   'GetAllProducts' is not an action that can bind to
>   'Collection([Entities.OpenApi.Products.ProductRef
>   Nullable=False])'.","ExceptionType":"Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Routing.DefaultODataPathHandler.ParseAtEntityCollection(IEdmModel
>   model, ODataPathSegment previous, IEdmType previousEdmType, String
>   segment)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Routing.DefaultODataPathHandler.ParseAtCollection(IEdmModel
>   model, ODataPathSegment previous, IEdmType previousEdmType, String
>   segment)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Routing.DefaultODataPathHandler.ParseNextSegment(IEdmModel
>   model, ODataPathSegment previous, IEdmType previousEdmType, String
>   segment)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Routing.DefaultODataPathHandler.Parse(IEdmModel
>   model, String odataPath)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.Match(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, IHttpRoute route, String parameterName, IDictionary`2 values,
>   HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)"}

What am I missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had this today.

Change

```
builder.EntitySet<ProductRef>("ProductSet");
```

to:

```
builder.EntitySet<ProductRef>().Collection.Action("GetAllProducts");
```

Add

```
[HttpPost]
public IQueryable<ProductRef> GetAllProducts(string StoreId, string flag)
```

This page helped me: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-actions